# Flask: How to get uploads folder path

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to get the uploads folder path.

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
```

I upload the images in the path:

```
.
└── uploads
    └── img_articles
        └── 2017
            └── 02
                └── image.jpg
```

I want to use image.jpg in a Jinja Template

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <img src="{{image_path}}" alt="">
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

What should I do?

Comment: I think you want to make that directory `STATIC_FOLDER`. Or put your uploads directory in your static folder. Flask will only serve static content out of your static directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Uploading Files Pattern](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/fileuploads/) in the information for the Pros.

Define a route for your uploads:

```
from flask import send_from_directory

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename)
```

In your template you can then use the route to get your filename

```
<img src="{{ url_for('uploaded_file', filename='yourimage.jpg') }}">
```

Comment: I tried and I got error 404: GET http://localhost:7000/uploads/img_articles/2017/02/image.jpg [HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND 3ms]

Comment: Remove the leading slash in your UPLOAD_FOLDER as it will otherwise refer to your `/uploads` instead of `./uploads`